# Can we claim multiple home planets?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've found an habitable base on a planet but the sentry is frenzied so I don't know if I should stay there. My thought is if I claim this base, will I be able to have another one or leave this one for another?

Comment: most probably yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As suggested from @warface I copy & paste my comment as new answer:*

With the newest NEXT update (1.53) you can build several bases (on the same or on different planets). But you always start from scratch with only the base computer. Then you have to build all the needed stuff again (Refiner, Teleporter, Buildings...).

The only exception seems to be the big storage container. You have to build it again too, but your content is available immediately and is always the same in every new storage container. At least at my actual level where I can have only 1 [storage container](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Storage_Container).

And just for the record:
You can fill this container from everywhere, but you have to travel back to (one of) your storage container(s) to pickup some items.

Answer (score 9):

From [this article](http://www.thesixthaxis.com/2016/11/27/no-mans-sky-foundation-update-is-out-now/), yes you can claim multiple home bases/planets, but you will have to start over each time. You can't have multiple at one time.

> Base building sounds great, letting you claim a home planet and build an uninhabited base into your own outpost – you’ll have to start over if you find a prettier planet and want to build a base there instead.

Comment: Does "starting over" mean that everything you did with your old base is lost, or just that you need to build each new base from scratch while keeping the old one?

Comment: With the newest NEXT update (1.53) you can build several bases (on the same or on different planets). But you always start from scratch with only the base computer. Then you have to build all the needed stuff again (Refiner, Teleporter, Buildings...). The only exception seems to be the big storage container. You have to build it again too, but the content is available immediately and is always the same. At least at my actual level where I can have only 1 [storage container](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Storage_Container) .

Comment: @PeterCo you should add you comment as a new Answer, it's true that the new NEXT update added the features to have multiple homebase.